# Rails: DateTime of different time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a `project` model with a datetime attribute to define the deadline. The deadlines are of different time zones, and I receive them in a string format like below:

```
Jan 1st 2013 00:00:00 EST
Feb 9th 2013 23:59:00 PST
```

I want to store these values in the default UTC format in the database. I've seen that there are many options to parse the time like `Time.zone.parse` and `Time.parse`. My question is: what's the best practice to parse the datetime of different time zones? I'm using `Rails 3.2.9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not worry about that at all, as long as you set correct timezone in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

You just assign the time strings to the attributes, ActiveRecord will convert it correctly.

```
1.9.3p125 :002 > project.deadline = "Jan 1st 2013 00:00:00 EST"
 => "Jan 1st 2013 00:00:00 EST" 
1.9.3p125 :003 > project.deadline
 => Tue, 01 Jan 2013 05:00:00 UTC +00:00 
1.9.3p125 :004 > project.deadline = "Feb 9th 2013 23:59:00 PST"
 => "Feb 9th 2013 23:59:00 PST" 
1.9.3p125 :005 > project.deadline
 => Sun, 10 Feb 2013 07:59:00 UTC +00:00
```

ActiveRecord uses `Time.zone.parse` to parse the strings internally.

Comment: I'm new to rails, and it seems like magic to me! BTW, in my `project` model, I have a method called `is_emergent?` which compares `Time.now` with `project.deadline`, and in my view file, I have a page displaying all the emergent projects. Qs: 1)Does `Time.now` also use the default configured time zone? 2)Does the page show the deadline in the viewer's time zone format or I need to use some js to retrieve the user's local time zone?

Comment: 1) When comparing two times, the time zones do not affect the result. You can get current time with `Time.zone.now` or `Time.now`. Both should be OK. 2) The page shows the deadline in the configured time zone by default. You can convert the time zone with `deadline.in_time_zone(...)`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Since "EST" and "PST" do not take day light saving into account, I replace them with "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" and "Pacific Time (US & Canada)". The weird thing is `Pacific Time (US & Canada)` calculates the same offset as `Eastern Time (US & Canada)`. I've scratched my head but got no idea why this happens.

Comment: See following examples: `Time.now.in_time_zone "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` => Fri, 21 Dec 2012 03:54:39 EST -05:00, `3.month.ago.in_time_zone "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` => Fri, 21 Sep 2012 04:55:01 EDT -04:00. The offset depends on the time.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `Time.parse` it will convert the timestamp to your configured timezone in rails. For example, my rails app runs in EST.

```
[5] pry(main)> Time.parse('Jan 1st 2013 00:00:00 EST')
=> 2013-01-01 00:00:00 -0500
[6] pry(main)> Time.parse('Feb 9th 2013 23:59:00 PST')
=> 2013-02-10 02:59:00 -0500
```

Notice the `+3:00hrs` for the `PST` timestamp used to get the result into my EST timezone.

To get the UTC version of each timestamp, just call `utc`

```
[7] pry(main)> Time.parse('Jan 1st 2013 00:00:00 EST').utc
=> 2013-01-01 05:00:00 UTC
[8] pry(main)> Time.parse('Feb 9th 2013 23:59:00 PST').utc
=> 2013-02-10 07:59:00 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks! So I just need to set `@deadline = Time.parse('Jan 1st 2013 00:00:00 EST').utc` and save it to my db, right?

Comment: You can get answers to a lot of your questions by **trying it**, Chelsea. Put `Time.now.zone` into console and see what it returns. The answer to your question below is **yes**, `Time.now` uses the Rails-configured timezone by default.

Comment: As for saving it to the database, Rails will automatically convert timestamps to UTC before storing it in the database, and back to your configured timezone when pulled out. As long as `@deadline` is a valid `Time` instance, it will convert the `EST` time to `UTC` before storing it.

Comment: I've tried that in console. I have not changed my rails app's timezone which means it should be "UTC" as far as I understand. But when I run `Time.now.zone`, it shows `"EST"` which is my local timezone. Timezone issues are really confusing to a newbie like me...